# Union of $2$ set $A, B$ where $ A$ is a subset of $B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I just started Set theory And I have the following question.
Suppose I have $2$ sets, $A$ and $B$. $A$ is a subset of $B$ (contained inside $B$), then the union of these $2$ sets is $B$ right $?$ If no, could you guys explain to me why, if yes, could you guys provide a simple proof.

Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The union of $A$ and $B$ is $B$ in that case and it is proved as follows:

$A \subset B \Rightarrow A \cup B \subset B \cup B \Rightarrow A \cup B \subset B$. (Because $B \cup B = B$).

Answer (score 3):

If $x\in A\cup B$ then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. If $x\in A$ cause $A\subset B$ then $x\in B$. If $x\in B$ then $x\in B$ is a right statemnt. Overall, $x\in A\cup B$ leads to have $x\in B$ eventually.